# Cannot push to Heroku git

Tags: git, heroku, composer-php

I want to push my codebase to heroku but it keeps giving me this error.

```
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
remote:        !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "WebProfilerBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle".
remote:        !!  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /tmp/build_94588dca9a8bf16fcac3d5d4c60e4ba5/src/Kernel.php:23
remote:        !!  Stack trace:
remote:        !!  #0 /tmp/build_94588dca9a8bf16fcac3d5d4c60e4ba5/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(424): App\Kernel->registerBundles()
remote:        !!  #1 /tmp/build_94588dca9a8bf16fcac3d5d4c60e4ba5/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(130): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
remote:        !!  #2 /tmp/build_94588dca9a8bf16fcac3d5d4c60e4ba5/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(159): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
remote:        !!  #3 /tmp/build_94588dca9a8bf16fcac3d5d4c60e4ba5/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(65): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands()
remote:        !!  #4 /tmp/build_94588dca9a8bf16fcac3d5d4c60e4ba5/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Cons in /tmp/build_94588dca9a8bf16fcac3d5d4c60e4ba5/src/Kernel.php on line 23
remote:        !!  
remote:        Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
remote:  !     WARNING: There was a class not found error in your code
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !     
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !     
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
remote:  !     - Composer vendor dir found in project!
remote:  !     - There was a class not found error in your code
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to dry-waters-62883.
remote:
```

Comment: Can you successfully run `composer install` in a brand new clone of your repository on your local machine? What's causing Heroku to try running `cache:clear`? Is that defined in your `composer.json`? Or maybe your `Procfile`?

Comment: cache:clear is defined in the composer.json. And I can run "composer install" also.

Comment: What's inside `post-install-cmd` in your `composer.json`? Add your scripts section to the question please.